# Rewrite to add a query string in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I know this can be done using a wordpress function but I'd like to add this rule in my htaccess file.

Basically I want to add a parameter to the URL and then let wordpress go about its business..

I have this

```
RewriteRule ^events/all/ /events/?all [L]
```

But I'm getting a 404 when I try and go to /events/all/

Thank you for any advice

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add that rule *before* any wordpress rules. Wordpress routes everything to `index.php` and if the routing happens before any specific rewrites that you have, those rewrites will never get applied.

Additionally, wordpress uses the request information to handle routing, so it may see `/events/all/` as the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` var and get confused. So wordpress may not be able to go about its business, depends on how you've setup the wordpress end of things.

If for whatever reason it's still not playing nice with wordpress, you could try adding the `P` option to internally proxy the request:

```
RewriteRule ^events/all/ /events/?all [L,P]
```